# Significantly different results between Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha with large radicals and small numbers

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries, numerical-value

I have some code which involves tiny numbers being put to the power of very large numbers. The function I'm looking at is

$\varphi = \omega(T) \left(1 - (1 - \epsilon)^{n_{e}(T)} \right)$

when $\epsilon $ is very small (~$10^{-16}$) and $n_{e}$ is large ($> 10^{10}$). Both $n_{e}$ and $\omega$ are known functions of $T$. At a known value ($T = 37$) the value of $\varphi$ is known, and we can in theory estimate $\epsilon$ by

$\epsilon = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{\varphi}{\omega} \right)^{\frac{1}{n_{e}}}$

However, when I put this into Mathematica I'm getting very strange behaviour; here's a MWE when $\varphi(37) = 0.2506$;

```
gammaex = 0.2506; 
omega[t_] := 2.43163218375*10^7*Exp[1700*(1/298.15 - 1/(273.15 + t))];

w[t_] := (3.414105049212413*10^12)/(omega[t]); 
v[t_] := Sqrt[661.6469313477045*(t + 273.15)];
ne[t_] := (v[t]*5.104757516005496*(10^7));

epsilon = SetAccuracy[ 1 - ( 1 - gammaex/w[37])^(1/ne[37]), 30];
test = w[37]*(1 - (1 - epsilon)^(ne[37]))
```

Now when I evaluate $\varphi(37)$ via the last line I should get the value 0.2506 but I do not; instead I get $\varphi = 0.289104$, over 15% off the true value. I thought maybe this was a precision problem, so I tried some other commands (Surd, Power...) and got the same wrong value. The output value for the epsilon is $\epsilon \approx 1.11 \times 10^{-16} $ from mathematica.

However I've evaluated this with WolframAlpha and got a markedly different value of $\epsilon \approx 9.61 \times 10^{-17}$, and as [this link demonstrates](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28112608%29*%281%20-%20%20%28%201%20-9.61369%20%C3%97%2010%5E-17%29%5E%282.31246*10%5E10%29%29) the calculation seems to work with WolframAlpha, returning close to the expected value around 0.25*. Any ideas why the calculations are different, and how I can make Mathematica behave with such extreme values?

Incidentally, if I dump the WolframAlpha equation ( (112608)*(1 - (1 - 9.61369*10^-17)^(2.31246*10^10)) ) directly into Mathematica, it still comes up with the wrong value, so I assume it's a radical issue?

Comment: You are using machine-precision numbers in `omega` and `v` (which I presume are Kelvin temperatures), so all the arithmetic is done in machine precision. Try, say, `27315/100` and report back.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean by 27315/100 ?

Comment: I mean, replace those machine-precision numbers in your definitions with exact quantities. I gave you one of them, and you should be able to see the other one to replace.

Comment: o37 = SetPrecision[omega[37], 30];

w37 = SetPrecision[w[37], 30];

v37 = SetPrecision[v[37], 30];

ne37 = SetPrecision[v37*5.104757516005496*(10^7), 30];

epsilon = SetPrecision[ 1 - ( 1 - gammaex/w37)^(1/ne37), 30];

I tried the above, but got the same mistake.. am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you certainly are, and I thought I was sufficiently clear, so here goes: **replace $273.15$ with $27315/100$ and similarly for the other Kelvin temperature you have** and try again.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis is right that it is a machine precision issue. When you switch to arbitrary machine numbers by placing say `30 after each decimal number, it evaluates to 0.25060000000000.

Comment: Thanks for this folks - I had tried converting the 1/273.15 to 1/(27315/100) and it kept producing the same error: When I changed it to 100/27315 it seems to work, but produces small imaginary components so I have to use Re[]. I would have thought SetPrecision or SetAccuracy would have stopped precision errors though?

Comment: Did you also put in $29815/100$?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't seem to work - this is the closest I can get (but produces a small imaginary part, using N similar to @FredSimons suggestion - of there's a cleaner way I'd be eager to know, what exactly causes this error? : omega[t_] := 
  2.43163218375*10^7*
   Exp[1700*(N[1/(298.15), 30] - N[(1/273.15), 30] + t)];

Comment: Also, if I use SetPrecision of 30 for every machine number, it agrees without the imaginary component. Thanks for all your helps guys (if either of you want to stick up the solution I'll happily upvote it) ..

Comment: Your construction `N[(1/273.15), 30]` is pointless; you cannot use `N[]` to raise a machine number's precision. And, since it seems to not have been already apparent to you: $29815/100$ and $298.15$ have completely different properties in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As J. M. already suggested, this is a machine precision issue. So let us do your computation with arbitrary precision numbers. For doing so, all machine numbers have to be replaced with arbitrary precision  numbers, otherwise the computation falls back to machine numbers. In the following command I have done this by placing `30 after each machine number.

```
gammaex=0.2506`30;
omega[t_]:=2.43163218375`30*10^7*Exp[1700*(1/298.15`30-1/(273.15`30+t))];

w[t_]:=(3.414105049212413`30*10^12)/(omega[t]);
v[t_]:=Sqrt[661.6469313477045`30*(t+273.15`30)];
ne[t_]:=(v[t]*5.104757516005496`30*(10^7));

epsilon=1-(1-gammaex/w[37])^(1/ne[37]);
test=w[37]*(1-(1-epsilon)^(ne[37]))
FullForm[test]
```

Now the result is what you expected:

```
(* 0.25060000000000000000000000000 *)
(* 0.2506`28.52376207789293 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rationalize` to convert numbers to exact numbers

```
gammaex = 0.2506 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
omega[t_] = 
  2.43163218375*10^7*Exp[1700*(1/298.15 - 1/(273.15 + t))] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;

w[t_] = (3.414105049212413*10^12)/(omega[t]) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
v[t_] = Sqrt[661.6469313477045*(t + 273.15)] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
ne[t_] = (v[t]*5.104757516005496*(10^7)) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

epsilon = 1 - (1 - gammaex/w[37])^(1/ne[37]);
test = w[37]*(1 - (1 - epsilon)^(ne[37]))
```

> 1253/5000

```
% // N
```

> 0.2506